# C# Derived Class wont Override base method

Tags: c#, linux, polymorphism, ubuntu-16.04, derived-class

Currently working on objects and classes.
I'm following an example given by my teacher, but its not working as its suppose to.
Note that I'm working on ubuntu instead of windows, and I'm not sure if that affects anything.

```
using System;

namespace AEDlc
{
    /**Base Classe Employee**/
    class Employee
    {
        private string name;
        public Employee(string PersonName)
        {
            name = PersonName;
        }
        public void ShowName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", name);
        }

        public virtual void ShowFunc()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Employee");
        }
    }

    /** Classe Employer **/
    class Employer : Employee
    {
        public Employer(string EmployerName) : base(EmployerName)
        {
        }
        /** New func "ShowFunc" **/
        public override void ShowFunc()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Employer");
        }
    }
    /** Main **/
    class KindaMain
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            /** worker array **/
            Employee[] worker = new Employee[]
            {
                new Employee("Base Dude"),
                new Employee("Base Dude 2"),
                new Employer("Boss Dude")
            };
            /** Show Info **/
            for (int i = 0; i < worker.Length; i++)
            {
                worker[i].ShowName();
                worker[i].ShowFunc();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The output from this is as it follows:

```
Base Dude
Employee

Base Dude 2
Employee

Boss Dude
Employee
```

And the output should be like this:

```
Base Dude
Employee

Base Dude 2
Employee

Boss Dude
Employer
```

Can anyone help me understand where I did wrong. Really can't find it...

UPDATE:
Somehow, I managed to fail closing a comment, so the entire method was commented out. Because i was working on nano, I didnt noticed this, just like alot of friends. So sorry for this post.
Should I just delete this post?

Comment: Your `ShowFunc` is commented out in `Employer` so it will take the base class implementation.

Comment: You are printing the name of the type with the `ShowFunc` method, which is hard coded to return `"Employee"`. The overriding method in `Employer` is commented out because the comment line that says `New func "ShowFunc"` doesn't have a closing `**/`, making it so your overriding method doesn't get compiled and therefore called.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's only a mistake in your comment here but in your Employer class you have commented out the ShowFunc method so the ShowFunc method on the Employee class will be called resulting in "Employee".

If it is just a mistake try stepping through your code so you can see which method is executed.

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you are not closing the comment  `/** New func "ShowFunc"` and it is commenting the ShowFunc override..

Try `/* New func "ShowFunc" */`

Comment: Yep, this is right. I feel really dumb right now, real sorry to make such a dumb post. Will update ASAP.